# duplicate path results on windows

Tags: python

I have a little problem, when I try to search files by extension, in this case on windows it returns duplicates.

```
_EXTENSIONS = ['*.md', '*.MD']
paths_found = []

for extension in _EXTENSIONS:
    results = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '**', extension), recursive=True)
    paths_found.extend(results)
```

results:

```
/root/folder1/README.md
/root/folder1/README.md
/root/folder1/README.MD
/root/folder1/README.MD
```

if in _EXTENSIONS I remove `.MD` then it does not return duplicates, but `.MD` and `.md` are different extensions

Comment: try using just one of those extensions. I think windows is case insensitive

Comment: make `paths_found` as `set` instead of list.

Comment: @Smurphy0000 already tried, if I use only one of those extensions it does not return duplicates, but on the mac it works differently

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/881804/case-sensitive-file-extensions-in-windows-and-linux#:~:text=answer%20was%20accepted%E2%80%A6-,In%20Windows%20you%20have%20case%20sensitive%20extensions%2C%20but%20you%20can,files%20in%20the%20same%20directory.&text=However%2C%20if%20you%20attempt%20to,the%20Open%20File%20dialog%20box.

Comment: Make it a set when everything is done( after "for" loop) like this -> `paths_found = set(paths_found)`

Comment: And on a side-note, you should try to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) when working with paths. It has a [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) alternative

Comment: In windows glob.glob() is not case sensitive, in Linux however it is.

Comment: thanks to all I solved by putting the set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a set when everything is done( after "for" loop) like this

```
_EXTENSIONS = ['*.md', '*.MD']
 paths_found = []

 for extension in _EXTENSIONS:
     results = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '**', extension), recursive=True)
     paths_found.extend(results)
 
 #this line is the key
 paths_found = set(paths_found)
```